# C# Entity Framework Not Updating Wpf GUI on Adding Data to Database

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, datagrid, entity

I have an Application with two Tabs in WPF.  One is Used to add a customer to the Database. The Other  tab displays the list of customers in a datagrid. My Problem is that when one adds a customer to the database, the new entry is not added into the Datagrid.In order for the customer to appear I have to close the application and rerun it. How can I ensure that when I add the customer it automatically appears in the list of customers in the datagrid? I am using Entity Framework..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework does not know about your tabs and grids, it dont know about WPF at all.

But you can:

1. Update grid manualy
2. Use ObservableCollection's.
3. Use http://waf.codeplex.com/
4. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.savingchanges.aspx
5. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

Comment: I would choose ObservableCollection over updating the grid manually where possible.

Comment: Depends. If there is only 2 tabs manual update would be enough.

Comment: I may need to have some controls e.g combobox which also has customer names. I need something that refreshes the controls automatically when the database is updated.Thanks though. @WayneTanner. I am using Observable collections. What do I need to implement?